# How do I remove the Clear button from p-calendar?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm implementing PrimeNG's `p-calendar` in an Angular application and I'm using the `showButtonBar` property.  I need the `Today` button to show, but I do not want the `Clear` button.

I'm not having any luck using `clearButtonStyleClass` in conjunction with a CSS class to just hide the button directly.

Here's my implementation:

```
`<p-calendar
[style]="{'width': '100%'}"
[inputStyle]="{'width': '100%', 'border': 'none', 'cursor': 'pointer'}"
[(ngModel)]="calendarDate"
[inline]="false"
dateFormat="DD, MM d, yy"
(onSelect)="calendarPickDate($event)"
[showIcon]="false"
[showButtonBar]="true"
(onTodayClick)="returnToTodaysDate()"
(onClearClick)="returnToTodaysDate()"
[clearButtonStyleClass]="'clear-button'"
[readonlyInput]="true"
</p-calendar>`
```

In my CSS for that Angular component, `clear-button` is as follows:

```
    .clear-button { display: none; }
```

I also don't get any traction by trying this syntax on the class property for the `Clear` button:

```
    clearButtonStyleClass="clear-button"
```

Comment: Try this css fix `.ui-input-text a {
 display: none !important;
}`

Comment: That did literally nothing.  I've succeed somewhat by putting `clear-button` class up into `styles.css` and changing its contents to `display: none !important`.  But now that just leaves the `Today` button centered in the left column of two 50%-width columns.  Looks odd.  Still scratching my head every time PrimeNG leaves me in these situations where elegance in the framework would seem a matter of common sense.  I'm not the only one to ever need to just have `Today`, not `Clear` on a datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with :

```
[clearButtonStyleClass]="'hideClearButton'"
```

in p-calendar html definition and :

```
::ng-deep .hideClearButton {
    display: none !important;
}
```

in my scss file.

The 'Clear' button just disappear without modifying the position of the 'Today' button.